# Ignore port numbers in haproxy host header matches

Tags: haproxy

Using haproxy-1.5, I have the following partial config:

```
    acl is_api hdr(host) -i api.example.com
    acl is_app hdr(host) -i app.example.com
```

Unfortunately, the above doesn't match a request that looks like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: api.example.com:80
```

Far as I can tell, I need to do:

```
    acl is_api hdr(host) -i api.example.com
    acl is_api hdr(host) -i api.example.com:80
    acl is_app hdr(host) -i app.example.com
    acl is_app hdr(host) -i app.example.com:80
```

UGH. NO! HATE!

Is there a nicer way of doing this? Can I just tell haproxy to ignore the port in the host header?

Answer (score 8):

You might be able to get this to work by checking hdr_dom (https://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/MatchingLayer7) instead of hdr:

```
acl is_api hdr_dom(host) -i api.example.com
acl is_app hdr_dom(host) -i app.example.com
```

Just be careful because I believe this would also match things like "otherstuff.api.example.com".

Comment: Depending on the use case `hdr_beg` may be more appropriate, it wont match on `otherstuff.api.example.com`. It will however match on the far less likely `api.example.com.otherstuff` (that `hdr_dom` also matches).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I've used this on the frontend:

```
http-request set-header host %[hdr(host),field(1,:)]
```

This won't match extraneous URLs and doesn't rely on a regular expression.

From https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/strip-port-in-host-header/4414/10